# How to extend width of output in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: kdb, jupyter-lab

I am using the [KDB kernel](https://github.com/KxSystems/jupyterq) inside [Jupyer Lab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab). I have a hard time having a quick look at my data because the output of my commands are truncated.

You can find an example in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb0p8.gif) where inputting:

```
flip (100#`a)!(100 2)#200?1f
```

would give a truncated output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the console size using `\c [h,w]` to prevent your output being truncated, however there is a limit of 2000 for both height and width.

If you put this in one of the cells of your Jupyter notebook and execute the cell to set the console width for all output in the notebook.

More information can be found here: [System Commands - Console Width](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/syscmds/#c-console-size)